# How to hide first 3 list items and show other items on button click?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have two scrollable lists (I attached a screenshot below). The first three elements of the list are purple, the remaining 4, 5 and 6 elements are green. I need to show only purple colors when clicking on the corresponding button, or show only green colors. I managed to make it so that when pressed, leave 3 purple elements and hide the green ones. But how can I make it so that I can hide more purple elements (the first 3 elements) and show only green ones?

```
List<Widget> _convertListItems(List<dynamic> list, bool isSecondList) {
  
  late List<Widget> children;
   if (isSecondList) {
     children = [
      for (var i = 0; !widget.isPowerAC || widget.isPowerAll ? i < list.length : i < 3; i++)
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
        child: Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            for (var j = 1; j <= list.elementAt(i); j++) Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 3),
              child: _itemPicture(list, i),
            ), 
          ],
        ),
      )
      
    ];
   } 
   else {
     children = [
      for (int i = 0; !widget.isPowerAC || widget.isPowerAll ? i < list.length : i < 3 ; i++) _item(list[i], i),
    ];
   }

    return children;
  }

  Widget _item(String? text, int pos) {
    return Align(
      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
      child: Container(
        height: 48,
        width: double.infinity,
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
          border: Border.all(
            color: currentPosition == pos
                ? pos < 3 
                  ? constants.Colors.purpleMain
                  : constants.Colors.green
                : Colors.transparent,
          ),
        ),
        child: Text(
          text!,
          style: currentPosition == pos
              ? constants.Styles.smallHeavyTimerTextStyleWhite
              : constants.Styles.smallerBookTextStyleWhite.copyWith(
                  color: constants.Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5),
                ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _itemPicture(List<dynamic>? list, int pos) {
     return SizedBox(
      height: 14,
      width: 9,
      child: Icon(Icons.bolt, color: pos <= 2 ? constants.Colors.purpleMain : constants.Colors.green),
     );
  }
}
```

**list**

```
List<String> list= [
    '7.4kW',
    '11kW',
    '22kW',
    '30kW',
    '150kW',
    '350kW',
  ];

  List<int> secondList = [
    1,
    2,
    3,
    1,
    2,
    3,
  ];
```

Answer (score 0):

before pass the list to the list view, make for loop and create new list that contain only purple ones and pass new list two list view.this way you can filter it and show what ever you want.